# Easy wifi router [web] interface for Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, router

There are plenty of instructions on the web about turning a Ubuntu system to a wifi router.  However, this is always done with command line operations.  I want something simpler.  Way simpler.

I use OpenWrt at home on my wireless router.  It as a very good web interface, very easy to use.  Is there anything like this for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the command line (iptables/firewalld) as much as possible you can run OpenWRT instead of Ubuntu if the sole use is going to be a router, if you want to use it as a PC at the same time install Virt-manager and then use the KVM virtual machine image of OpenWRT.

KVM https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/x86/kvm_guest/

x64 https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/x86/64/

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but you fail to find easy instructions on how to bridge and reroute networking traffic to the kvm instance.  I have no clue how to do this.  +1 for giving me an idea, but it is not the easy solution I am looking for.

Comment: Bridging a network interface is easy but it does requier a one time visit to the command line to set it up. After that you do everything from the desktop GUIs.